Fierz identity problem
I am trying to figure out whether the following has any meaningful transformation in Fierz identities. Suppose w's are either u or v spinors. Then $$ \overline{w}_1 P_L w_2 \; \overline{w}_3 P_L w_4 \overset{?}{=}\overline{w}_1 P_L w_4 \; \overline{w}_3 P_L w_2  .$$ Is any meaningful transformation possible. I have tried to break down the projection operators, and then there will be in total 4 terms. Using Fierz transformation on four of these terms isn't giving anything intelligible.
